# How to prevent update query from automatically running till open modal

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have recently been using [this modal script](http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/) to run a query on my page. However, when I put my update query in the modal content box, it automatically runs once the page is loaded. However, I want it to run once the user opens the modal box. So, here is my modal box code so far:

```
    <div class="md-modal md-effect-1" id="modal-1">
        <div class="md-content">
            <h3>SUCCESS!</h3>
            <div>
              <?php
              $id = $_GET['id'];
              $query = $db->query("UPDATE mybb_tnybracket SET player2 = '$username' WHERE tid = '$id' AND    player1 IS NOT NULL AND player2 IS NULL")or die(mysql_error());
               ?>
                <p>Content has been updated!</p>
                <button class="md-close">Close me!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-1">Update Information?</button>
```

I am unable to find any way to make the query wait until the modal is open. It makes sense why it would automatically run the query, but I need it to hold off until it's opened! Can anyone seem to help?

Comment: php doesn't run in the browser it runs on server. Read up on using ajax...lots of tutorials out there

Comment: That doesn't help me bud. I'm looking for tutorials specifically on this...